# ajax can read requests from several users at the same time?

Tags: ajax

I have a function that reads a dynamic form and sends it through ajax, the problem is when two users enter at the same time only saves the data of a single user and the other does not allow you to do anything until the end of the first.

Is there a method or function that allows me to read the data simultaneously?

Comment: Web workers should give you the functionality you want